# In python multiple a column across a columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like multiple a column across a columns. Is their a function which does this in Python?

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6],"c": [9, 5, 6], "d": [4, 9, 6]})
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({"w": [2, 4, 2])})
```

Would like to get the result:

```
 result = = pd.DataFrame({"a": [2, 8, 6], "b": [8, 20, 12],"c": [18, 20, 12], "d": [8, 45, 12]})
```

Is it possible to apply df2 across all four columns?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let's pass the numpy array:

```
df1.mul(df2.values)
```

If there are more columns in `df2` you can extract just column `'w'`:

```
df1.mul(df2[['w']].values)
```

Output:

```
   a   b   c   d
0  2   8  18   8
1  8  20  20  36
2  6  12  12  12
```

Comment: Can also explicitly use `axis=0` and pass the Series: `df1.mul(df2["w"], axis=0)`